# Display DropDownlist when click on specific cell asp.net table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to figure it out how can I display a dropDownList on a specific cell in the table right after clicking a button "Show DropDownlist" located on that cell.

This is the behind code , right now it is displaying the dropDownList at the last cell of each row. and I want to make it appear only when a button is clicked.

```
while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
                    myTable.Rows.Add(tRow);
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
                    {
                        // Create a new cell and add it to the row.
                        TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
                        if (i == 4)
                        { 
                            tCell.Controls.Add(SM_List());  //Adding the dropdownlist             
                            tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
                            continue;
                        }

                            tCell.Text = rdr.GetString(i);
                            tCell.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.cursor = 'pointer'; this.style.backgroundImage = ''; ");
                            tCell.Attributes.Add("onClick", "getData()");
                            tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);

                    }
                    /* iterate once per row */
                }
```

I want to add this code, so it will be a button at first , instead of a drop down list :

```
Button bt = new Button();
bt.Text = "Switch";
bt.Click += new EventHandler(DropDownList_Show);
tCell.Controls.Add(bt);
```

But I am not sure how to display the DropDownList at the exact cell the button was located. and also I want to do some actions when Value was selected in the dropdownlist.
Can you please assist , I feel a little bit lost.

Comment: Do you want to create dynamic button control

Comment: That would be easy if done in client side. Just pass this as an argument, and put the content at that cell using .html("dropdown html")

Comment: It would have been easier to handle this if you would have used GridView or DataGrid and used ItemTemplate to display controls, such as buttons and dropdownlist, in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this issue easily by using GridView in ASP.NET.
Let say the GridView is declared as following in ASPX page.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Token" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Secret" />
        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="ShowDropDown" Text="Show" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="dropDownList" runat="server" Visible="false">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Valid" Value ="1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Invalie" Value ="2"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Following is the method in code behind which populates the GridView.

```
private void BindGridView()
{

    var tokens = new List<AccessToken>();
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Server=somedbserver;Database=somedatabase;User Id=someuser;Password=somepassword;"))
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = conn;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT Id, Token, Secret FROM Tokens";

            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            conn.Open();

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var token = new AccessToken();
                    token.Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    token.Token = reader.GetString(1);
                    token.Secret = reader.GetString(2);
                    tokens.Add(token);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = tokens;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

And I am calling this method in Page_Load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGridView();
    }
}
```

Following is the event handler of RowCommand event of GridView which will display the dropdown list in the column next to the button which is clicked.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName == "ShowDropDown")
    {
        var row = GridView1.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];

        //Using Cell[4] coz the Dropdownlist is in 5th column of the row.
        //You need to replace 4 with appropriate column index here.
        //Also replace "dropDownList" with the ID assigned to the dropdown list in ASPX.
        var ddl = (DropDownList)row.Cells[4].FindControl("dropDownList");

        if(ddl != null)
        {
            ddl.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You will able resolve your issue if you follow this approach.